# how to get specific data in graphql

Tags: reactjs, graphql

this is my query:

```
query Employee($id: Int!) {
  employee(id: $id) {
    id
    FirstName
    LastName
    Age
    DateOfJoining
    Title
    Department
    EmployeeType
    CurrentStatus
  }
}
```

```
error in graphql : "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field Query.employee.",
```

how to get specific data in graphql ?

i have try many things to solve this problem

Comment: Probably need more info to answer this for you, but I'd suggest looking at your resolver and verify it's pulling and returning the employee information as you expect

Comment: query Employee($id: Int!) {
  employee(id: $id) {
    id
    FirstName
    LastName
    Age
    DateOfJoining
    Title
    Department
    EmployeeType
    CurrentStatus
  }
}
here is the my graphql query

Comment: when i run command : npm run watch in my terminal 
this error is coming: ERROR in ./JSX/employeeUpdate.jsx 25:0-46
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './graphQLFetch

Comment: @Colton is correct, the problem lies with your *resolvers* on your GraphQL *server*. The query itself is fine but the server is not doing its job.